# Shell script, find -name, and wildcard expansion

Tags: shell, find, quoting

I'm trying to use `find -name` in a `sh` script with a *previously computed* complex argument for the condition. Simplified, it goes like

```
cond="-name '*.txt*"
find . $cond -ls
```

But now I have the problem that either the wildcard in `$cond` is expanded by the shell before calling `find` or not expanded by `find`.

To test that, in an empty test directory I did:

```
touch a.txt b.txt c.dat
```

and then iterated

```
cond="-name '*.txt'"; echo $cond; find . $cond
```

with different values for `$cond`, using all types of quoting/escaping I could think of.

Either I get all four entries (including the `.` directory) or no files – or `find` complains about `b.txt` being an unknown primary or operator. Of course, the correct output should be just the two text files.

Any hints? I'm sure I'm just missing something basic.

Comment: `cond="-name *.txt"` should be enough

Comment: Of course with `set -f ; find . $cond ; set +f`

Comment: Costas: thank you, that's how I do it now.

Comment: See also  [But what if …?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/80216#286350 "Implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Bourne-like shells (except `zsh`), leaving a variable expansion unquoted in list context is the *split+glob* operator. In:

```
cond="-name '*.txt'"; echo $cond
```

The content of `$cond` is first split according to the value of the `$IFS` special variable. By default, that's on ASCII space, tab and newline characters.

So that's *split* into `-name` and `'*.txt'`. Then the *glob* part is applied. For each of those *words* that contain wildcard characters (here `*` in the second one), the word is expanded to the list of files that match that pattern or left untouched if no file is matched. So, `'*.txt'` would expand to the list of files in the current directory whose name starts with `'` and end in `.txt'` or to `'*.txt'` if no file matches.

That list of words is then passed as separate arguments to `echo`. If no file matched, that means `echo` will receive 3 arguments: `"echo"`, `"-name"` and `"'*.txt'"`.

Of course, the same applies for the `find` command.

You want the `find` command to receive the arguments `-name` and `*.txt`, so you need to tune your *split+glob* operator.

You need the value of `$IFS` to match the separator you use in `$cond`. So for instance:

```
cond='-name:*.txt'
IFS=':'
```

And you don't want the *glob* part of the *split+glob* operator, so you need to disable it with:

```
set -f
```

So it becomes:

```
cond='-name:*.txt'
IFS=:; set -f
find . $cond -ls
```

Or you could do:

```
cond='-name *.txt'
set -f
find . $cond -ls
```

and assume `$IFS` has not been modified from its default value.

Alternatively, if your shell supports arrays, you may want to use that instead of relying on a scalar variables and expecting the shell to split it upon expansion.

This would work with `ksh93`, `mksh`, `bash` or `zsh`:

```
cond=(-name '*.txt') # an array with two elements: "-name" and "*.txt"
find . "${cond[@]}" -ls # elements of the array expanded as separate arguments
                        # to find.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I now just switch off blobbing locally, and it works like a charm. Regrettably, I cannot vote up your answer yet.

Comment: @Stefan, beware that `set -f` disables globbing altogether (not only the implicit globbing done upon variable expansion or command substitution). That means `rm -- *.txt` for instance won't work anymore. You may also want to consider better shells that don't perform globbing upon variable expansion like `zsh`, `rc` or `fish` (of those, `zsh` is the most _Bourne_-like).

Comment: (and of course it should read "globbing" — damn autocorrect ;-))

Comment: I have a `(` … `)` construct around the `find`, so I assume `set -f` stays local — right? For portability reasons, I prefer to keep at "classic" Bourne Shell.

Comment: @Stefan, yes `(...)` and `$(...)` create a local context for options and variables, usually by forking a subshell process.